# Get Facebook access token from Android Account settings

Tags: android, facebook, oauth

Is this possible ? 
I wish user with attached FB account (in Android settings) don't have to enter credentials in FB WebView Oauth dialog (in my app), but have only to push OK button and agree with authentication.

AFAIK this is possible on IOS.

Comment: No, it's not possible. Are you explicitly specifying the webview during login? The default goes to the FB app (if installed) for SSO, and does not require further login.

Comment: Unfortunately not all users have FB app. I specify SSO mode with WebView fallback